# Get distinct column values into varchar value

Tags: sql-server, for-xml

I have a large query, and in it a subquery in which I try to get all distinct rows from a temporary table column

```
(SELECT
        STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT #SomeTemporaryTable.CountryName
        FROM #SomeTemporaryTable
        WHERE (#SomeTemporaryTable.SomeId = 1
        AND #SomeTemporaryTable.AnotherId = 2)
        FOR XML PATH(''''),TYPE).value(''(./text())[1]'',''VARCHAR(MAX)'')
    ,1,2,'''') AS BreakDownLocationCountry,
```

The problem is that I am receiving the following error:

The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Can someone please help me?

P.S : Microsft SQL 2008

Comment: `Microsft SQL 2008` - this makes me cry, why are you punishing yourself by using an obsolete and completely unsupported platform? Also I don't think you included enough of your query to help solve the error message (I don't see `ORDER BY` anywhere). Can you please build a _minimal_ demonstration of the problem at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk)? e.g. CREATE TABLE, INSERT, and a _minimal_ query that generates the error (we sure don't need your whole query).

Comment: I am not punishing myself. My boss is punishing me :))

Comment: `ORDER BY` goes on the line above `FOR XML`

Comment: Why are you your single quotes "doubled up"? That isn't valid syntax (unless this is part of some larger dynamic statement you aren't showing us, but then you should be making the above representative of what you're actually trying to achieve). Also the error you are getting isn't related to the above; there is no `ORDER BY` clause.